# Android/Java. Что лучше использовать если необходимо загрузить с сервера много изображений и отобразить в LIstView?

Tags: android, многопоточность, listview, android-asynctask, imageview

Если в `ListView` загружая отображать сразу 1000, 5000, 10000+ изображений..
Там же будут тормоза?

Вопрос:

Как более оптимально без тормозов это сделать и 
что лучше использовать - `AsyncTask` или `Handler`? или есть еще более лучше способы (оптимизированные)?

Comment: Почему будут тормоза? ListView сделана так, что вьюшек не будет создано 1000++, а будет создано ровно столько сколько влазит на экран. Они переиспользуются, потому тормозов не должно быть.

Comment: AsyncTask вам в помощь и комментарий выше

Answer (score 3):

Используйте ленивую загрузку.

`RecyclerView` или `ListView` плюс паттерн `ViewHolder`.

Библиотеку для загрузки изображений, например Picasso.